# How to write a C++ program to write multiplication tables?

Tags: c++

How can I write a C++ program to print all the multiplication tables from 11 to 20 up to first 10 multiples of each? And what are some good resources to learn C++ online?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to learn proper C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963019/how-to-learn-proper-c)

Comment: "How to write a C++ program to write multiplication tables?" - open a text editor and type code that displays multiplication tables.

Comment: suspecteedd homework with no effort

Comment: You can do this quite easily with nested `for` loops.

Comment: If this is for homework, I suggest you learn about artificial intelligence and neural networks.  Write an application in a complex or exotic programming language (like APL), program a neural network, feed it a set of known multiplication networks, let it adjust itself to the input for a few months, and then ask it to generate new multiplication tables.  You should get the results in a few months or years.  If you just want to learn C++, get a book.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
    std::cout << "11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40" << std::endl;
    //...
    std::cout << "110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190 200" << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to do it with some specific construct (like two nested `for`-loops looping over the interval 11:20 and 1:10), try and ask so.

Comment: Yes, I want to do this with for loops.

Comment: Then have a try. Look at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: Next time if someone gives you the hint that for loops should be used, try searching the internet. There are *lots* of resources.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // setw

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    for( int y = 1; y <= 10; ++y )
    {
        cout << setw(3) << y << ": ";
        for( int x = 11; x <= 20; ++x )
            cout << setw(4) << x*y;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope these will help you,

```
int main() {
    int i, num;
    num = 11;
    while(num <= 20){
        for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
            std::cout<<num*i<<std::endl;
        }
        num ++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

let me know if any queries?

Comment: `void main()` is not C++.

Comment: Sorry,I thoughout your are working on Turbo c++.Make changes inplace of void main() use int main and at last return 0;